# Align line numbers to right hand side on odd pages in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am compiling a booklet, so I am using mirrored margins. I can adjust everything (header / footer, etc.) to work with the even / odd pages to ensure that the page numbers appear on the outside of the pages, etc.

But now I am trying to put line numbers in (as the book has ancient poetry). I would like to have the line numbers on the outside of the pages, but can't even figure out how to get the line numbers to align right, let alone getting them to simply go to the "outside" part of the page. I have to be missing something on the right-align part. Does anybody know what?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the document that you'd like your line numbers to be right-aligned in.
2. Under "Page Layout" (Word 2013) enable Line Numbers for your document.
3. Use Alt+F11 to open VBE.
4. Paste the following code in the "Immediate Window". If the Immediate Window is not visible (most likely at the bottom of your screen), enable it using Ctrl+G.

   ActiveDocument.Sections(1).PageSetup.SectionDirection = wdSectionDirectionRtr
5. Hit the "Enter" key on your keyboard to run this script. **Do Not** click the Run Macro button in the toolbar, use the enter key.
6. Save and close your document. Your line numbers may have vanished, that's fine.
7. Click Start > All Programs > Microsoft Office > Microsoft Office Tools > Microsoft Office XXXX Language Settings/Preferences
8. Select "Hebrew" in the Available Editing Languages box.
9. Click "Add" then click "Ok".
10. Reopen your Word document.

Your line-numbers should be on the right margin of your document.  If not then look under Paragraph options and adjust the (section) direction to right-to-left.

Do not forget to go back to languages preferences and remove Hebrew after you get your printed documents, but beware that doing so before you've printed it will result in the line numbers being removed.

This is based on [this document](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/line_numbering.html) which I tested successfully prior to using as an answer.

Comment: I realise that I'm commenting on a very old answer, but in my experience steps 1-5 do the job without me needing to do 6-10 :)